# Is there any way to read messages from Kafka topic without consumer?

Tags: testing, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Just for testing purpose, I want to automate scenario where I need to check Kafka messages content, so just wanted to know if it is possible to read messages without consumers directly from TOPIC using Kafka java libraries?

I'm new to Kafka so any suggestion will be good for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could SSH to the broker in question, then dump the log segments into a deserialized fashion, but it would take less time to simply use a consumer in any language, not necessarily Java

"For testing purposes" Kafka Java API provides MockProducer and MockConsumer, which are backed by Lists, not a full broker